# Deserialize a JSON from Google Translation API using C#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm using Google Translation API to detect a language of a string. The API is returning this JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "detections": [
            [
                {
                    "confidence": 0.37890625,
                    "isReliable": false,
                    "language": "ro"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I still haven't found the way of deserialize it. I'm using `System.Runtime.Serialization` and this is my code:

```
[DataContract]
public class GoogleTranslationResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember(Name = "detections")]
    public List<Detection> Detections { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Detection
{
    [DataMember(Name = "confidence")]
    public decimal Confidence { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "isReliable")]
    public bool IsReliable { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
// ...
var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(GoogleTranslationResponse));
result = (GoogleTranslationResponse)jsonSerializer.ReadObject( new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(responseData)));
```

I'm getting this as a result:

```
Confidence: 0
IsReliable:false
Language:null
```

Comment: `"detections"` is an array of arrays. Do you need to model that using a list of lists?

Comment: @Brian Rogers I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JSON, the value of `"detections"` is a 2d jagged array:

```
"detections": [ [  { ... } ] ]
```

Therefore your model needs to reflect this by using nested collections:

```
[DataContract]
public class Data
{
    [DataMember(Name = "detections")]
    public List<List<Detection>> Detections { get; set; }
}
```